# Excel VBA File not Found

Tags: vba, excel, filenotfoundexception

During the development of some Excel vba code, in about every other iteration where I go in, add some code and then save the file, the next time I open it, I get a "File not Found" error. The macro is set to automatically run the code upon opening the file.

To fix it, I copied all the code - modules and classes plus the startup code - to a fresh blank excel file. I save the excel macro file and it runs fine.

This happens for both Excel 2003 and 2007.  What is happening here?

Comment: What is your code doing?

Comment: I have found that just by adding blank lines in between lines of code the error goes away.  Appears to be an excel bug, not much that can be done about it.

Comment: Just to add my $0.02. Before the weekend, I deleted the contents of one of the cells in a worksheet and today I'm seeing the File Not Found issue on open after months of zero issues. I never would have considered that making a simple change like that could affect the function of the Workbook_Open routine. My solution was to completely delete the Workbook_Open routine, create a brand new one using the drop-down, and then paste the original code back in. Now works without issue.

Comment: I still want to know what file is not being found...anybody know how to root that out using commands in the Immediate window or by some other means? "File Not Found" is a ridiculously vague error...which file? where is it? what line of code is trying to find the file?

Answer (score 0):

My psycho powers tell me you are relying on relative paths while changing the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a similar phenomenon, though I'm not sure the cause is the same.

Yesterday, every time I added a Workbook_Open procedure to my workbook, saved it and reopened it, I got the "File not found" error (no particular file specified). followed by "We found a problem with some content in [workbook name]. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?". If I said Yes to recovering, I found that all the VBA code was gone from the workbook.

It turned out that this was caused by my virus checker (BitDefender), which considered my code to be malware and was removing code from the workbook. I tried it on a PC with a different virus checker (BullGuard) and it did something similar. At least BullGuard had the decency to tell me it was modifying my file. BitDefender didn't give me any clue at all!

On a general point, as someone who does VBA work for many different clients, I'm finding more and more problems with virus checkers getting in my way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have solved your problem.

One possibility is that one of your module is too long.

VBA is a compiled size limit for 64kb. It is "supposed" to warn you if you exceed that, but often it fails.

Find out the longest Module that you have, move some function out to another module and see if it helps.

I have this often.